# Store HTML into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, html, jdbc, longtext

I'm trying to store a `String` which contains HTML in a MySQL database using `Longtext` data type. But it always says "You have an error in your SQL syntax". I tried to store a normal `String` and it works.

**Update**:

This is the query:

```
st.executeUpdate("insert into website(URL,phishing,source_code,active) values('" + URL + "','" + phishingState + "','" + sourceCode + "','" + webSiteState + "');");
```

I'm using Java.

Comment: Chances are you're not escaping your text.  What language are you using to interact with mySQL?

Answer (score 9):

Strings in a SQL query are -usually- surrounded by singlequotes. E.g.

```
INSERT INTO tbl (html) VALUES ('html');
```

But if the HTML string itself contains a singlequote as well, it would break the SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (html) VALUES ('<form onsubmit="validate('foo', 'bar')">');
```

You already see it in the syntax highlighter, the SQL value ends right before `foo` and the SQL interpreter can't understand what comes thereafter. SQL Syntax Error!

But that's not the only, it also puts the doors *wide* open for [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) ([examples here](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)).

You'll really need to sanitize the SQL *during* constructing the SQL query. How to do it depends on the programming language you're using to execute the SQL. If it is for example PHP, you'll need [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (html) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($html) . "')";
```

An alternative in PHP is using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), it will handle SQL escaping for you.

If you're using Java ([JDBC](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html)), then you need [`PreparedStatement`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html):

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tbl (html) VALUES (?)";
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, html);
```

**Update**: it turns out that you're actually using Java. You'll need to change the code as follows:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO website (URL, phishing, source_code, active) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, URL);
preparedStatement.setString(2, phishingState);
preparedStatement.setString(3, sourceCode);
preparedStatement.setString(4, webSiteState);
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Don't forget to handle JDBC resources properly. You may find [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html) useful to get some insights how to do basic JDBC stuff the proper way. Hope this helps.

Comment: While using prepared statements prevent you from sql injection, do remember to escape the HTML when you pull it out and display it again ! If you do not, you'll be vulnerable to all sort of xss attacks.

Comment: @nos: completely right. That's however a story apart. Seeing the coding (variable names) as far, I'd expect it to be used for completely different purposes though :) @jouzef19: if this HTML is coming from *user input* and you are *ever* going to display this in a JSP page or so, then use [`fn:escapeXml()`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/escapeXml.fn.html) to sanitize it to avoid [XSS attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) - [examples here](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

Answer (score 2):

Try using `mysql_real_escape_string` function on the string you want to store. It is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape a string before inserting it into database.

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to say without seeing the query. Can you post it?

I'm presuming there's some part of the html string that needs escaping, which maybe you missed?