# Is there any way to insert string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `Template`. In that I have one column like `Message`.For example

```
-------------------------------
id  name  desc cretaedBy  Message
-------------------------------
1    A     blah  today      <td><tr>one</tr></td></body></html>
2    B     blah  lastday
3    C     blah  onemonth   <tr><td>last</td><td>next</td></tr></body></html>
```

Here, i need to insert `<div>blah blah some content</div>` before `</body></html>` in `Message`-column.

How to find the position and update in particular position using update query.

This table shows 3records for example only..but it may contain1000records. Actually what i am expecting, for example if java or any programming language...if string contains end body tag ,  substring the string and add data before end body tag.

Anyone please help me in mysql

Comment: How is the question related to `java`?

Comment: So you want to insert it into the same column? (row 3 column `Message`)

Comment: you would need to update the whole column for the specific row. Construct the new value for the column and then update

Comment: i have to insert in Message column where Message contains '</body></html>' .i have just shown 3 records. But this table contains 1000 records. i need to update where and all needed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store HTML into MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641561/store-html-into-mysql-database)

Comment: @shekhar-no..i want to execute if footer contains end body tag </body>, i want to insert some content before </body>

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `UPDATE` with a `REPLACE`, where you replace `</body></html>` with `<div>blah blah some content</div></body></html>`. In `Message` values which don't have `</body></html>` in them, nothing will happen:

```
UPDATE Template
SET Message = REPLACE(Message, '</body></html>', 'div>blah blah some content</div></body></html>')
;
SELECT * FROM Template
```

Output:

```
id  name    desc    createdBy   Message
1   A       blah    today       <td><tr>one</tr></td>div>blah blah some content</div></body></html>
2   B       blah    lastday     (null)
3   C       blah    onemonth    <tr><td>last</td><td>next</td></tr>div>blah blah some content</div></body></html>
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/44eff05/1)

If your table is very big, qualifying the `UPDATE` with `WHERE Message LIKE '%</body></html>'` will speed it up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an update statement:

```
UPDATE Template SET Message = '<tr><td>last</td><td>next</td></tr><div>blah blah some content</div></body></html>' 
WHERE Message = '<tr><td>last</td><td>next</td></tr></body></html>';
```

Comment: No. you are using  constant value in where condition.Some cases ,records wont contain no data in Message . i am asking if footer contains </body></html> ,  I have to insert 'data'  before </body></html> .

Comment: Please put that information into your question. So you have to insert data before </body></html> but sometimes it's empty so what do you want then?

Comment: Hi willem thanks.i have updated my question .  1000 records already there...if message column contains </body> , i need to add some data before </body>...so if some records contains no data in message column , i should not update corresponding the record..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Create template DDL statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'a name comment',
  `Message` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'an address comment',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`))
```

Create template INSERT data statement:

```
Insert into mytable (name,message) VALUES('A','<td><tr>one</tr></td>?</body></html>')
...
Insert into mytable (name,message) VALUES('C','<td><tr>last</tr></td>?</body></html>')
```

Use Prepare. Your data will be inserted into the SQL query template at the question mark place.

```
    mysql> PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'Insert into mytable (name,message) VALUES('A','<td><tr>one</tr></td>?</body></html>');
Insert into mytable (name,message) VALUES('C','<td><tr>last</tr></td>?</body></html>');';
mysql> SET @a = '<div>blah blah some content</div>';
mysql> EXECUTE stmt1 USING @a;
mysql> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```

Create and fill in the table with the data whenever necessary.

Comment: Hi thanks.but i need to write update script...bcoz already records there..i want to update wherever message column contains </body>

Comment: then export the whole table along with its contents to a sql file and perform the replacement in a text editor. Then drop your table and run the script.